# What is the result of using the "as operator" on a null object?

Tags: c#

C# has the `as` keyword which can cast an object into something else, or fail and return null if it doesn't work.

What happens if the value I try to as cast is null already? Do I get null out or does it throw some exception?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It would return null. The `as` operator's purpose is to avoid throwing an exception, per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion
>   isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

For example:

```
object o = null; // also try with a string type
string result = o as string;
Console.WriteLine(result); // null
```

Answer (score 7):

[Why not try it?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v0ZS6s)

You get a null value, no exception. Actually, the point of `as` is to never throw an exception.